# How to shrink the background image of a select element?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I use the bootstrap `form-select` select element :

```
<select class="form-select listbox_length_menu_datatable"
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
    <option value='20'>20</option>
    <option value='30'>30</option>
    <option value='-1'>Tous</option>
</select>
```

here is the style :

```
.listbox_length_menu_datatable {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    background-image: url(icones/triangle-black.png);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0.58em;
    font-weight: 650;
    padding-left: 0.4rem !important;
    padding-top: 0.1rem !important;
    padding-bottom: 0.1rem !important;
}
```

At runtime it gives like this : [image]

So how to reduce the width and height of the background-image of the select element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can do is that you can insert an svg into the css and then you can control the size of the arrow there.

Here is 3 dropdowns with different size arrows in them

```css
.listbox_length_menu_datatable {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 0.58em;
  font-weight: 650;
  padding-left: 0.4rem !important;
  padding-top: 0.1rem !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem !important;
  background-position: calc(100% - 0.75rem) center !important;
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  appearance: none !important;
  padding-right: 2rem !important;
}

.listbox_length_menu_datatable.small {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg height='5px' width='5px' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7.247 11.14 2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z'/></svg>") no-repeat;
}

.listbox_length_menu_datatable.medium {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg height='10px' width='10px' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7.247 11.14 2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z'/></svg>") no-repeat;
}

.listbox_length_menu_datatable.large {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg height='20px' width='20px' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7.247 11.14 2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z'/></svg>") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select listbox_length_menu_datatable small">
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
  <option value='20'>20</option>
  <option value='30'>30</option>
  <option value='-1'>Tous</option>
</select>

<select class="form-select listbox_length_menu_datatable medium">
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
  <option value='20'>20</option>
  <option value='30'>30</option>
  <option value='-1'>Tous</option>
</select>

<select class="form-select listbox_length_menu_datatable large">
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
  <option value='20'>20</option>
  <option value='30'>30</option>
  <option value='-1'>Tous</option>
</select>
```